# How to make a few words in an embed bold and the rest normal text? Also, how to add reactions button to a bot message?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make this bot send a custom message like so

[image]

This is an embed and '**ALERT - BOUGHT**' is bold but the rest of the text is normal. How can I achieve this?
I have been looking up how to do it all day.
I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a text in discord bold by surrounding it with double asterix: **

So that embed's description is: ":bell: **ALERT** - **BOUGHT** - HD AUG etc"

It's called markup and theres [more fun to be had with it](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-)

Comment: Thank you so much for this.
Also, can you please tell me how to get this specific type of embed.
 
embed.add_field(name=chr(173), value=f":bell **ALERT - B -**{current_last_tweet.full_text}")

currently I'm using this but it doesn't get the same output as the one in the picture.

Comment: I dont quite get what you mean with 'this specific type'

Comment: It's just a normal embed with color set to white and description set to the text you see

Comment: I think so anyways, its quite a thin embed somehow and i dont know how exactly its so thin :D, maybe text above it idk, your image is quite cropped